# Encypt XML file with AES and storing on disk

Tags: java, security, xml, cryptography

I have written some code to encrypt XML and then store it on the disk. I want to be sure that the encryption code is secure, so here is the code:

```
package com.application;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Aes {

    public Aes() {
    }

    public String encrypt(String data, String key) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            String iv = generateRandomIv();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(key), makeIv(iv));
            return iv + System.getProperty("line.separator") + new String(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String data, String key) throws WrongPasswordException {
        String decrypted = "";
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            String iv = getIv(data);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(key), makeIv(iv));
            decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(removeIvFromString(data).getBytes("ISO-8859-1")), "ISO-8859-1");
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new WrongPasswordException();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    private AlgorithmParameterSpec makeIv(String iv) {
        try {
            return new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String generateRandomIv() {
        return new RandomStringGenerator().randomString(16);
    }

    private String getIv(String data) {
        return data.substring(0, data.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
    }
    private String removeIvFromString(String data) {
        return data.substring(data.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator")) + 1, data.length());
    }

    private Key makeKey(String encryptionKey) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] key = md.digest(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.application;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStringGenerator {
    private char[] vowelLowerCaseLetter = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
    private char[] consonantsLowerCaseLetter = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'};
    private char[] numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    private char[] specialCharacters = {'!', '"', '@', '#', '£', '¤', '$', '%', '&', '/', '{', '(', '[', ')', ']', '=', '}', '?', '+', '\\',
            '´', '¨', '~', '^', '*', '\'', '-', '_', '.', ':', ',', ';', ' ', '½', '§', '<', '>'};
    public String randomString(int length) {
        char[] upperCaseLetter = convertCharsToUpperCase(ArrayUtils.addAll(vowelLowerCaseLetter, consonantsLowerCaseLetter));
        char[] lowerCaseLetter = ArrayUtils.addAll(vowelLowerCaseLetter, consonantsLowerCaseLetter);
        char[] allowedCharacters = ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.addAll(lowerCaseLetter, upperCaseLetter), ArrayUtils.addAll(numbers, specialCharacters));
        String randomString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            randomString += getRandomCharacter(allowedCharacters);
        }
        return randomString;
    }
    private char getRandomCharacter(char[] allowedCharacters) {
        Random r = new Random();
        return allowedCharacters[r.nextInt(allowedCharacters.length)];
    }
    private char[] convertCharsToUpperCase(char[] lowerCaseLetter) {
        char[] upperCaseLetters = new char[lowerCaseLetter.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lowerCaseLetter.length; i++) {
            upperCaseLetters[i] = Character.toUpperCase(lowerCaseLetter[i]);
        }
        return upperCaseLetters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Binary data != string

```
public String encrypt(String data, String key) {
    ...
        new String(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")), "ISO-8859-1");
    ...
}
```

Here you get a `byte[]` with the input data encrypted. This is arbitrary binary data.

**Do not treat binary data as strings.**

It only works because you are using an encoding with a single byte per character.

When you want to store binary data as a string you should use [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoding instead:

```
import java.util.Base64;

public String encrypt(String data, String key) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String iv = generateRandomIv();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(key), makeIv(iv));
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String base64CipherText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);
        return iv + System.getProperty("line.separator") + base64CipherText;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String decrypt(String data, String key) throws WrongPasswordException {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String iv = getIv(data);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(key), makeIv(iv));
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(removeIvFromString(data));
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        throw new WrongPasswordException();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Now that the encoding issues are fixed you should consider using [UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) (or another portable encoding) for the [`String.getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

Answer (score 1):

```
public Aes() {
}
```

The empty constructor is redundant. :)

Your code seems to rely a lot on `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, perhaps make that as a constant? Alternatively, if you are already on Java 7, there's [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--).

I'm not too sure about your implementation for `RandomStringGenerator`... For starters, why not make `allowedCharacters` a `private static final` field, and the same for the rest as well? You may also want to consider using [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) over `Random`. You can also probably consider having only one `RandomStringGenerator` per `Aes` instance, as I don't think there's much benefit to instantiating `RandomStringGenerator` every time when calling `generateRandomIv()`.